# Tikzpicture - Functional Analysis Tree is forced to the top of the page - want to center to the page center

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting

First time posting on this forum. I utilized a template to produce this functional analysis tree. (Not completely finished yet, as I want to get the formatting right first). But when I compile this, the figure is forced to the top of the page and is not centered in the page center. I am unsure how to do this, as I have tried a lot of possibilities from looking through this forum.

Thank you very much for any kind of help!

```
\documentclass[a3paper]{article} % say
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{center}


\resizebox*{1\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=2mm,
place/.style={circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick},
transition/.style={rectangle,draw=black!50,fill=black!20,thick, minimum 
width={width("Allow installation")+2pt}}, skip loop/.style={to path={-- ++
(0,#1) -| (\tikztotarget)}},
hv path/.style={to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}},
vh path/.style={to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}}]]


\node at ( 0,10) [transition, align=center] (one) {Improve\\Tonearm};
\node at ( -12,8) [transition, align=center] (two) {Enhance 
User\\Experience};
\node at ( 6,8) [transition, align=center] (three) {Extract Quality\\Audio};

\node at ( -18,6) [transition, align=center](fam1row11){Allow easy\\record 
switching};
\node at ( -14,6) [transition, align=center](fam1row12){Meet 
budget\\constraints};
\node at ( -10,6) [transition, align=center](fam1row13){Enable 
easy\\installation};
\node at ( -6,6) [transition, align=center](fam1row14)
{Complement\\aesthetic};

\node at ( -18,4) [transition, align=center](fam1row21){Include 
intuitive\\mechanism};
\node at ( -12,4) [transition, align=center](fam1row22){Include 
auto\\adjustment};
\node at ( -8,4) [transition, align=center](fam1row23)
{Allow\\customization};


\node at ( -15.5,2) [transition, align=center](fam1row31){Allow  
feedback\\mechanism};
\node at ( -12,2) [transition, align=center](fam1row32){Include 
intuitive\\controls};
\node at ( -8.5,2) [transition, align=center](fam1row33){Include\\calibrated 
dials};






\node at ( -2,6) [transition, align=center]{Improve\\Tonearm};
\node at ( 6,6) [transition, align=center]{Improve\\Tonearm};
\node at ( 12,6) [transition, align=center]{Improve\\Tonearm};
\node at ( 14,6) [transition, align=center]{Improve\\Tonearm};
\node at ( 18,6) [transition, align=center]{Improve\\Tonearm};
\node at ( 24,6) [transition, align=center]{Improve\\Tonearm};
\node at ( 26,6) [transition, align=center]{Improve\\Tonearm};

\node at ( -2,4) [transition, align=center]{Improve\\Tonearm};
\node at ( -2,2) [transition, align=center]{Improve\\Tonearm};

\node at ( 6,4) [transition, align=center]{Improve\\Tonearm}; 
\node at ( 2,4) [transition, align=center]{Improve\\Tonearm};
\node at ( 10,4) [transition, align=center]{Improve\\Tonearm};

\node at ( 1,2) [transition, align=center]{Improve\\Tonearm};
\node at ( 3,2) [transition, align=center]{Improve\\Tonearm};

\node at ( 5,2) [transition, align=center]{Improve\\Tonearm};
\node at ( 7,2) [transition, align=center]{Improve\\Tonearm};

\node at ( 10,2) [transition, align=center]{Improve\\Tonearm};

\node at ( 12,4) [transition, align=center](fam2row25){Improve\\Tonearm};

\node at ( 14,4) [transition, align=center](fam2row26){Improve\\Tonearm};
\node at ( 15.5,2) [transition, align=center](fam2row37){Improve\\Tonearm};

\node at ( 17,4) [transition, align=center]{Improve\\Tonearm};
\node at ( 19,4) [transition, align=center]{Improve\\Tonearm};

\node at ( 22,4) [transition, align=center]{Improve\\Tonearm};
\node at ( 24,4) [transition, align=center]{Improve\\Tonearm};
\node at ( 26,4) [transition, align=center]{Improve\\Tonearm};

\node at ( 23,2) [transition, align=center]{Improve\\Tonearm};
\node at ( 25,2) [transition, align=center](fam2row39){Improve\\Tonearm};






\draw [->] (one) to (two);
\draw [->] (one) to (three);

%\draw [->] (two.south) to (fam1row11.north);
%\draw [->] (two.south) to (fam1row12.north);
%\draw [->] (two.south) to (fam1row13.north);
%\draw [->] (two.south) to (fam1row14.north);

\graph {
(two.south) ->[skip loop=-5mm] (fam1row11.north);
(two.south) ->[skip loop=-5mm] (fam1row12.north);
(two.south) ->[skip loop=-5mm] (fam1row13.north);
(two.south) ->[skip loop=-5mm] (fam1row14.north);

(fam1row11.south) ->[skip loop=-5mm] (fam1row21.north);
(fam1row13.south) ->[skip loop=-5mm] (fam1row22.north);
(fam1row13.south) ->[skip loop=-5mm] (fam1row23.north);

(fam1row22.south) ->[skip loop=-5mm] (fam1row31.north);
(fam1row22.south) ->[skip loop=-5mm] (fam1row32.north);
(fam1row22.south) ->[skip loop=-5mm] (fam1row33.north);


(fam1row23.south)->[skip loop=-5mm] (fam2row25.south);
(fam1row23.south)->[skip loop=-5mm] (fam2row26.south);
(fam1row23.south)->[skip loop=-5mm] (fam2row37.north);
(fam1row23.south)->[skip loop=-5mm] (fam2row39.north);
%(p2) ->[skip loop=5mm] (p5);
%(p6) ->[skip loop=-11mm] (p9);
%(p7) ->[vh path] (plus) -> [hv path] (p8);
%(p7) ->[vh path] (minus) -> [hv path] (p8);
};

\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{center}


\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your `tikzpicture` inside a `figure` environment instead of a `center` environment.

```
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
....
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{if required \label{if required too}}
\end{figure}
```

The `[p]` option places the figure on a separate page

Comment: Thank you, I have no idea how I missed that. Really appreciate it!

Comment: No trouble, happy to be of help !